# Can I use onChange handler in an input without providing the value prop?

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering whether I can use the input with the onChange handler without providing any value,
when I tried the code it is working fine but I am not sure whether this method is correct or not.

```
export const SearchInput: React.FunctionComponent<SearchInputProps> = ({
  onChange,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group form-search">
      <i className="fa fa-search form-search-icon"></i>
      <input
        type="text"
        maxLength={200}
        onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have asked the same question in the react forum and was informed that this is expected to work.
https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/3195